# How to generate loop for n times with conditionals in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have function like this:

### Heading

```
x1 = x1_l + np.random.beta (alpha_x1, beta_x1)*(x_u1 - x_l1)       
y1 = y1_l + np.random.beta (alpha_y1, beta_y1)*(y_u1 - y_l1)       
z1 = z1_l + np.random.beta (alpha_z1, beta_z1)*(z_u1 - z_l1)
```

conditional:
should meet CR_Criteria <=0.1 then collect the x1, y1, z1, and repeat until 5000
times. If not meet the conditional, then repeat the function from the beginning.

note :CR criteria = (x1+y1+z1)/3

How can I generate the code in python.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? I feel like working on somebody's homework. Also more context will be helpful: Are `x1_l, alpha_x1, beta_x1, x_u1...` all constants? Do you want to meet the criteria within 5000 times? If all variables are constants, why are there such a limit (5000) because each repetition will practically be the same like starting from scratch no matter if there is a limit or not.

Comment: I have tried but only run one time, I need to make it as a loop for 5000 times (Montecarlo). x1_l and x1_u= constant,  alpha_x1 & beta_x1 are variable, actually, this formula is generating a random number based on beta PERT distribution formula. I want to repeat 1000, 2500, and 5000 times because I want to run Montecarlo simulation.

Comment: I also tried another way : x1 = x1_l + np.random.beta (alpha_x1, beta_x1, 5000)*(x_u1 - x_l1) . However, using this way, all the 5000 data are a mix of data which met criteria and not meet criteria, I also don't know to separate the data that I need.  So, there are 2 ways in my mind for solving this issue: 1. nested loop and 2. flat and separate them. But I am stuck in both ways. I have very long code for this, so I can give you my code in an email. Thanks a lot